# X and Y-axises is duplicated when major_formatter is set

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I have a code to plot an empty graph:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import pyplot, dates

pyplot.yticks([0,1,2,3,4])

ts_start = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=1)
ts_end = datetime.now()
delta = timedelta(minutes=10)

x_dates = dates.drange(ts_start, ts_end, delta=delta)
pyplot.xlim(x_dates[0], x_dates[-1])
# fmt = dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# pyplot.axes().xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)

pyplot.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)
pyplot.xticks(x_dates)

pyplot.show()
```

[image: empty_graph]

I want to display time in format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' on y-axis, not int.

But when adding major_formatter to xaxis (commented lines) I get duplicated X/Y axes (+xlim/ylim crashes):

[image: crashed]

pyplot.xticks()/pyplot.yticks() call return my ticks with timestamps/int.

How to do without set_major_formatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pyplot.axes()` creates new axes. If you want to get the current ones, either save a handle when creating them explicitly (which you currently don't do) or use `pyplot.gca()` to get the current axes.

It is recommended to make these things explicit:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3.5))

ax = fig.add_subplot()  # or use the optional arguments to put more than one axes in the figure

ax.plot(...)
ax.set_xlim(...)
ax.set_xticks(...)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(...)
```

This way it is clear what is being applied where, especially if you have multiple figures and axes.

The functions in `pyplot` (e.g., `pyplot.xticks()`) are mostly only thin wrappers around the functions on the axes (e.g., `ax.set_xticks()`) anyway.